# DOCTYPE and Character Encoding not recognized by w3.org validator

Tags: html

I've spend several hours trying to figure out what's wrong with the following html.

```
<!DOCTYPE=html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Location Status</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="location_status.css">
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="900">
</head>
```

validator w3.org tells me:

1. The character encoding was not declared.
2. End of file seen without seeing a doctype first. Expected `<!DOCTYPE html>`
3. Element head is missing a required instance of child element title

Comment: You're likely looking for `<!DOCTYPE html>`, without the `=`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `<!DOCTYPE html>` wasn't right and you forgot to close the `<html>` tag.
Here's the code in the right format:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">

    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Location Status</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="location_status.css">
        <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="900">
    </head>

    <body>
        // Your page code here
    </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You have forgotten to close your `<html>` tag. You should always remember to close the html tags otherwise it can create unecessary problems.
2. You have not used `<!DOCTYPE html>` correctly.
3. `<head>` requires a `<title>` tag which specifies the title of your page and it will appear whenever you will open your html page in the browser.
   Generally `<head>` contains all the metadata.

You can do like this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">

    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Title of your page</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="yourCSSFile.css">
        <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="900">
    </head>
    <body>
        // Your Code
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks folks, the bad "=" in DOCTYPE fixed things. I could have sworn I copied that from elsewhere, but so be it. The missing end html tag and no body tags I had omitted from the OP for clarity. Thanks again.

Comment: @MarkDiaz i hope if it helped... u can please accept it as your answer. :)

Comment: It's an answer that worked - don't know what you mean by "please accept"

Comment: @MarkDiaz you can tick on the answer which you feel is useful and is accepted by you.

Comment: @MarkDiaz this might help you to understand more about accepting answers on stackoverflow : https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work